# Use same EC2 instance for all AWS Data Pipeline activities

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I am using AWS Data Pipeline to import some CSV data from S3 to Redshift. I also added a ShellCommandActivity to remove all S3 files after the copy activity completed. I attached a picture with the whole process.

[image: Move S3 CSV data to Redshift using AWS data pipeline]

Everything works fine but each activity starts it's own EC2 instance. Is it possible that the ShellCommandActivity to reuse the same EC2 instance as the RedshiftCopyActivity, after the copy command completed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the ShellCommandActivity to run on the same EC2 instance, I edited my ShellCommandActivity using Architect and for the Runs On option a chose Ec2Instance. The ShellCommandActivity gets mapped automatically to the same EC2Instance as the RedshiftCopyActivity. Now the whole process looks like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can do all activities in shell or CLI, it is not possible to do everything in the same instance.

One suggestion I can give is to move on to new technologies. AWS Data Pipeline is outdated (4 years old). You should use AWS Lambda which will cost you a fraction of what you are paying and you can load the files into Redshift as soon as the files are uploaded to S3. Clean up is automatic and Lambda is much more powerful than AWS Data Pipeline. The tutorial [A Zero-Administration Amazon Redshift Database Loader](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx24VJ6XF1JVJAA/A-Zero-Administration-Amazon-Redshift-Database-Loader) is the one you want. Yes, there is some learning curve, but as the title suggest it is a zero administration load.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to follow that tutorial but from what I understood, Lambda functions require that your Redshift cluster to be publicly accessible and there is no other way to do that for now. See this blog post: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-redshift-loader/issues/30. For me it's a must that the Redshift cluster not to be publicly accessible. Our infrastructure is based on VPCs.

Comment: @Radu-StefanZugravu check out: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/

Comment: I tried that too. Even if I add a s3 endpoint, my lambda function times out: Task timed out after 59.00 seconds. If I get my lambda function outside VPC, it successfully gets the uploaded s3 file. Any idea? Thank you!